# Expo - Failed to create App Store app. The Bundle ID you entered has already been used

Tags: react-native, expo, app-store-connect, ipa

I am using `eas build` followed by `eas submit` to publish my react-native app to the Apple App Store.

The first `submit` always goes through but the subsequent submissions give this error:

```
✖ Failed to create App Store app xxx. 
The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used - The Bundle ID you entered has already been used.
The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used on this account. - The app name you entered is already being used for another app in your account. If you would like to use the name for this app you will need to submit an update to your other app to change the name, or remove it from App Store Connect.
Please visit https://appstoreconnect.apple.com and resolve any warnings, then try again.
Error: Submission failed
```

This is my second attempt to create a new app and update its version via expo eas service. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue but not sure where to see the warning that tells me what attribute has already been used.

I'm submitting same app with Expo with different bundle id to be able to white label the same code base with different apps in the app store.

Thanks for help!